# Java toggling value of boolean not working

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to toggle the boolean `playerTurn` to allow me to control to methods. However, it is not working, the methods will not move, nor will it print out the other print statement.

```
moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            diceRoll();
            private boolean playerTurn = true;
            if(playerTurn == true)
            {
                moveC1Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                System.out.print(diceRoll());
                System.out.print("Moving counter 1");
                playerTurn = !playerTurn;
            }else if(playerTurn == false)
            {
                moveC3Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                System.out.print(diceRoll());
                System.out.print("Moving counter 3");
                playerTurn = !playerTurn;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: your else is the same as the first if statement... also you should check the scope of your variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is your action:

1. I roll the dice
2. It's my turn!
3. Yes, it's my turn, so I move up, repaint and it's not my turn
4. I exit

And still the same... Something is wrong... The second if cannot be ever executed.

Solution:
make a playerTurn variable inside a higher class instead off creating it in ActionListener each time.

Use debugger and analyse how the program is working, than you'll see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really make sense what you are doing there. The playerTurn variable has local scope, which means that it won't be "saved" between two clicks. It should have another scope, e.g. be a private field of the containing class. Furthermore you are checking in both conditions whether playerTurn is true. The else branch will never be used.

Edit: You should also use println, as it is possible that a simple print won't result in a flush of the stream.

Comment: When declaring the var as private it give the error: `Illegal modifier for parameter playerTurn; only final is permitted`

Comment: Also, the code has been updated, please see if that is what you mean

Comment: The variable is inside a method. Move it outside of the method, but inside the anonymous `ActionEvent` class, and make it private.

Comment: No. It is still a local variable (with invalid modifier) and not a field of the class. You might want to take a look into some Java books or tutorials for a better understanding of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `playerTurn` as a parameter.
My advice would implementing the code as a method

```
public void update(boolean playerTurn)
{
   moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            diceRoll();
            if(playerTurn)
            {
                moveC1Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                System.out.print(diceRoll());
                System.out.print("Moving counter 1");
                playerTurn = !playerTurn;
            }else
            {
                moveC3Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                System.out.print(diceRoll());
                System.out.print("Moving counter 3");
                playerTurn = !playerTurn;
            }
        }
    });
```

would work. You are setting the boolean variable as `true` before you write a condition.

Comment: It is fine, it is all fixed. Thanks!